# Is it possible to simulate key press ALT once and releasing in CMD using POWERSHELL?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, simulation

I try to use the following code to simulate the keyboard to press the "alt" key and then release it.
However ,the code doesn't  work

`powershell.exe -Command "[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%');"`

Does this code not work with the ALT key alone?

Comment: This code is to write a batch file of command prompt characters which is used to start and run a program, and one of the steps needs to press "alt" to switch the menu。

Comment: @mklement0In order to write a BAT that can quickly start the program in my office computer, because the office computer cannot use other unauthorized programs, the .bat file is the only feasible solution.
Then switch the menu part. At present, if I want to use the keyboard simulation method, I can only jump to this column by pressing "ALT", just like pressing ALT on the Chrome screen will jump to the menu in the upper right corner.

Comment: Have you tried using `%%` instead of `%` (a syntax requirement to use a verbatim `%` in a batch file)? It seems to work _intermittently_ for me - not sure what it depends on. Note that the keypress is sent to _whatever application has the input focus_, so unless you run the batch file hidden or explicitly activate the target window, it will be sent to the console window running the batch file (where pressing Alt alone seemingly never has any effect).

Comment: It should be possible to test it with your method just now, thanks for the assistance . @mklement0